# Why senders email does not show up while using javaMail API in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have written a sample JSP code to send email to another user using JavaMail API. The form has sender email box, subject box, and comments section. All the three html fields will be retrieved using **request.getParameter()** in jsp file. Email is being sent perfectly from the host (smtp.gmail.com), but then I see it is sent as myself when i logged into gmail (In other words sending email for myself) . The below is the sample code I have been working on:

```
'<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>

<%@ page isErrorPage="true"  %>

<%
   String result;
   // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
   String to = "toABC@gmail.com";
   final String username = "toABC@gmail.com";
   final String password = "somePassword";
   // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
   String from = request.getParameter("senderEmail");



   // Get system properties object
   Properties properties = new Properties();  

   // Setup mail server

    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");


   Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(properties,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()         {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
              });

    try{
       // Create a default MimeMessage object.
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
       // Set From: header field of the header.
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
       // Set To: header field of the header.
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                new InternetAddress(to));
       // Set Subject: header field
       message.setSubject(request.getParameter("subject"));
       // Now set the actual message
       message.setText(request.getParameter("content"));
       // Send message
       Transport.send(message);
       result = "Sent message successfully....";
     }catch (MessagingException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       result = "Error: unable to send message....";
       out.println("<br>");
       out.println("<p>" + ex.getMessage() +" </p>");

     }
  %>


   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>


 <body>
   <center>
      <h1>Send Email using JSP</h1>
   </center>
   <p align="center">
 <% 
     out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
  %>
 </p>
 </body>
 </html>`
```

And the below is my HTML page:

```
    <html>
<body>
 <form action="htmlEmail.jsp" method="post">
        <table border="0" width="35%" align="center">
           <caption><h2>Send New E-mail</h2></caption>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">Sender email address </td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="senderEmail" size="50"/></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Subject </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subject" size="50"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>Content </td>
                <td><textarea rows="10" cols="39" name="content"></textarea>    </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send"/></td>
           </tr>
          </table>

    </form>




</body>
 </html>
```

In the HTML page I am entering senders email address which I thought would be shown as senders email when I open my Gmail account after running the above code on the server. Instead, I am receiving email from "toABC@gmail.com". My query is, "why I am not getting email as it is sent by "fromXYZ@gmail.com" (which is entered in the html form )?". As you can see in the code I am using **message.setFrom(from)** for sender. This should then appear to me as sender in my email. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `from` is finding the correct value? Try sending it in the content so you're sure it's not setting `from` to null and defaulting to your email.

Comment: @stvcisco...I have concat the "from" string to message.setText(request.getParameter("content") +" "+from). I can see the fromXYZ@gmail.com in my received email content. Remember it is in content but not the sender. Sender is still myself as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

In general, mail servers aren't going to let you send mail that appears to come from any arbitrary address.  If there's a specific other address that you want to send mail from, see [this Gmail help page](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370).

Comment: @Bill...I am more or less using below link to understand the Javamail api along with jsp. What the code in below link states is that user can have both from EMAIL address, but I am not sure whether the person whoever has posted the code was able to receive email from the sender. I have gone through your link, I will give a try but before that I will do few more tweaks in my code and then will post again in here. [link to the example:](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jsp/sending-e-mail-with-jsp-servlet-and-javamail)